# Add column with cell values to tables merged using Query

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-query-language

I use this Query formula in Google Spreadsheet to merge tables from many source sheets into one table:

`=query({Data1!A4:B;Data2!A4:B;Data3!A4:B}; "select * where Col1 is not null")`

To distinguish original tables in the merged table, I need to add new column to the merged table with their identification. The indentification string is in cells on every source sheet. How to do it?

This is example spreadsheet I prepared for tests. Copy it to your Google Drive to make changes please.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YimEsiDa3gTiKqv7DMohfNvBDruvQ13zrK23Y3R3Gsw/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* the simplest way is the "long-winded" add a column in each sheet (say a new "A") and populate that with the sheet name, so then a query like so:

```
=query({Data1!A4:C;Data2!A4:C;Data3!A4:C}; "select * where Col2 is not null")
```

Edit re Comment:

Not the layout required but at least differentiates the source without adding anything to the sources:

```
 ={query(Data1!A4:B,"select * where A is not NULL label A '"&Data1!B1&"'");query(Data2!A4:B,"select * where A is not NULL label A '"&Data2!B1&"'");query(Data3!A4:B,"where A is not NULL label A '"&Data3!B1&"'")}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not modify the source sheets. They are generated by Google Analytics Extension for Google SpreadSheet in my real application. No formulas can't be added to the sheets, because they are everytime generated from scratch by the extension.

I fixed the Data2 cell, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the new solution. The result is a little different, but it could be managable by formulas now I think.